# no main manifest attribute, in myFile.jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, jar

I have a problem with the creation of my API jar written in spring.

The problem is that every time I try to run my docker image the error is: "no main manifest attribute, in myFile.jar"

The API must be deployed on my RaspBerry pi

I share a little more details ->

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'me.myddns.findyourhome'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '12'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.5.RELEASE'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'me.myddns.findyourhome.ApiDispatcher'
}
```

(me.myddns.findyourhome.ApiDispatcher is the name of the folder of the of the main class, I try to add .MainFileName, but nothing change)

Dockerfile

```
FROM hypriot/rpi-java

COPY ApiDispatcher.jar .

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "ApiDispatcher.jar"]
```

I don't know where the error can come from, so if you need some other details to help me, let me know.

thanks in advance!

**SOLVED**

The problem was that Intellij in the import of the project had confuse some directories. I solved in reimport the project as a gradle project, like a new import!

Hope I can help some one else in my situation :D

Comment: Remove the manifest section from bootJar. Remove the jar task completely. Use the Spring Boot gradle plugin as documented. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-main-class

Comment: plugins {
 id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
 id 'java'
 id 'application'
}

application {
 mainClassName = 'me.myddns.findyourhome.ApiDispatcher'
}

But it does not work jet @JBNizet

Comment: Read the link I provided. The application plugin doesn't generate an executable jar file. it generates a zip file wontaining the application jar, all its dependencies, and script files to run the application. If you want an executable jar file, don't use the application plugin.

Comment: @JBNizet I need to deploy to let the api ready to be called. It is my first api project, so I'm not really an expert in it. I give a look to the guide, but the error remains the saim

Comment: I can't help you without the code and without the error.

Comment: What code do you need? I'll share it

the error is: no main manifest attribute, in ApiDispatcher.jar

Comment: Your gradle build script.

Comment: So, again: do NOT use the application plugin.

Comment: Ok I edited the old post @JBNizet

Comment: ok @JBNizet, I try with and without application plugin, I think the problem is somewhere else. Can you help me with some code? Try to answer with a correct gradle :/